# How can I create a PHP session from one remote server to another?

Tags: php, session, single-sign-on, jwt

I have ServiceSite.com (SS) and multiple GameSite.com's. All games authenticate through SS and then log in with their own personal databases. That's all done with a simple JSON API, no need to log into SS to get into a game.

I have the one goal of logging into a game and accessing the features of SS through the game, such as accessing a player's Contact List and Profile, both of which are shared between all games. While in `GameSite.com/play`, they'll hit a link to `ServiceSite.com/contacts` and get the response as if they were opening it from `ServiceSite.com`. I use **JSON Web Tokens** to manually log the user into SS, to simulate a real login to `ServiceSite.com`.

**This works... so long as they're on the same domain.** Meaning, as I'm developing a game, I'll use `ServiceSite.com/tempgameurl` and any call to `ServiceSite.com` has no problem establishing and keeping a session. But once the game gets its own domain, or if I'm working on my localhost, I cannot get it to recognize the session on subsequent requests. If I want a response, I will always have to pass the JWT token, which is not suitable for what I'm doing. The goal is to load a game, "poke" SS to create a log in, and then if a player were to visit `ServiceSite.com`, they would have the session as if they'd logged into `ServiceSite.com`'s front page with their login manually.

In short, I expect that once I hit my first JWT request and make a session on `ServiceSite.com` from a `GameSite.com`, that's it, the session is made. But it seems to only actually make a session if I'm requesting from the same domain. I do see it create a session properly, filling in $_SESSION, but that data simply does not persist if the request originates from a non-`ServiceSite.com` URL.

Comment: You could use a centralized session store, like Redis

Answer (score 2):

Sessions and Cookies are domain dependent, it is a browser security issue. You cannot cheat this. However, there is a "trick" you can try, even though it is a bit more complex:

You need to set a cookie for each domain:

1. authenticate the user, emit a JWT code and create a key=>value type of record in a shared storage (database most likely). The key should be unique, the value should be JWT code and also set an expire time of 20-30 seconds.
2. in the response HTML you need to make the browser set cookies for the other domains. That can only be done on those domains. So you need to fool it with something like:

   `<img src="http://anotherDomain/setCookie.php?key=keyFromSharedStorage" style="display:none;" />`
3. in the setCookie.php, check the shared storage and retrieve the JWT based on the $_GET['key']. Then set a cookie with that JWT.

You could pass the JWT directly, but passing a key that expires fast should be more secure. Add an image for every domain.

Instead of a cookie you can create a session on each domain. Same principle really.

Comment: Seems this may not be what I truly want. I could always pass around the JWT token, but I don't want the complexity. What bothers me is that I'm pinging from GameSite.com, I'm doing a `print_r()` on the session created on ServiceSite.com, and yet it doesn't persist merely because the request spawned from GameSite.com. That makes me wonder if I can then have a second request to achieve what I want: make the request to SS.com, then at SS.com, send itself a request essentially identical to the one it would have gotten from GameSite.com, just originating from SS.com's domain. I'll have to try soon.

Answer (score 0):

Well try saving your needed data and sessions in database itself. It seems to be small amounts of data and logs.

After a game save the sessions on the database and open from whichever place you are at.